# android using ViewPager to show images

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'd like to download a bunch of images from web and then show them using my custom PagerAdapter. So I can slide to browse all of these images.

I define an activity named as `PhotoSlideActivity` which extends from `FragmentActivity`. In this activity, I have my own `PagerAdapter`. The following is my code:

```
    private class PhotoSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final int mSize;

        public PhotoSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int size) {
            super(fm);
            mSize = size;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            PhotoUrl photoUrl = new PhotoUrl(position);
            return PhotoSlidePageFragment.create(photoUrl.makePhotoUrl());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mSize;
        }
    }
```

The following is my `PhotoSlidePageFragment`. `mImageFetcher` is a class which download images asynchronously.

```
   public class PhotoSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_slide_page, container, false);
       mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   }

   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

       // Use the parent activity to load the image asynchronously into the ImageView
       if (PhotoSlideActivity.class.isInstance(getActivity())) {
          mImageFetcher = ((PhotoSlideActivity) getActivity()).getImageFetcher();
          mImageFetcher.loadImage(mImageUrl, mImageView);
       }
   }
```

(1) My original idea is to put `mImageFetcher.loadImage(mImageUrl, mImageView);` in `onCreateView`. Is there any difference between putting it in `onCreateView` and in `onActivityCreated`?

(2) What if I replace what I did in `onActivityCreated` with `mImageFetcher = new ImageFetcher(); mImageFetcher.loadImage(mImageUrl, mImageView);`? Doing this means use `Fragment` to load the image asynchronously. Is there any bad effects doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use LazyList for fetch data from the website(URL).
download following example from Github

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

and adapter data use in swipe change image example

https://github.com/chiuki/android-swipe-image-viewer